# Supremum of set

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $S$ be a nonempty subset of the real numbers that is bounded above. The upper bound $u$ is said to be the *supremum* of $S$ if and only if, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an element $x_\varepsilon \in S$ such that $u−\varepsilon < x_\varepsilon$.

Ok this is the definition but...

What if I would change "$u−\varepsilon < x_\varepsilon$" with "$u−v \le x_\varepsilon$"?

I checked for an interval, for a set of separated points, for a single point, but the definition works with the above substitution.("$u−\varepsilon < x_\varepsilon$" with "$u−\varepsilon \le x_\varepsilon$").

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Please format your posts using MathJax (see the link above for reference). For first time users, you can expect others to edit your question for you, but after asking 9 questions and being a member for over a year, you are expected to do the formatting yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing changes.

Let's call $\mathscr{S}$ the “strict” definition (with $<$), and $\mathscr{L}$ the “lax” definition (with $\le$).

It is clear that a number $u$ satisfying $\mathscr{S}$ also satisfies $\mathscr{L}$.

Suppose $u$ satisfies $\mathscr{L}$. Given $\varepsilon>0$, we want to find $x_\varepsilon$ such that $u-\varepsilon<x_\varepsilon$.

Since $u$ satisfies $\mathscr{L}$ we are able to find $y\in S$ such that $u-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\le y$. Since
$$
u-\varepsilon<u-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\le y
$$
we can take $x_\varepsilon=y$.